# Reactjs cookie is empty in subroute using universal-cookie

Tags: reactjs, cookies, routes

everytime before the app loads i check the cookie in order to determine where to navigate.

I check the cookies in a method inside of App.js.

These are the three Routes iam using in the App.js named checkCookies().

```
 import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
 import _ from "lodash";

 checkCookies();

class App extends Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/car"
            component={Car}
          />
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/car/bmw"
            component={BMW}
          />
        </Switch>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="Ferrari" component={Ferrari} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
   )
  }
}
```

The code for the checkCookies method is the following:

```
checkCookies(){
    let model = cookies.get("model");
    if(_.isEmpty(model) || model==""){
       // do this
    }
 }
```

when i try to access a cookie in the route "/car" it works but when i try to access the cookie in the route "/car/bmw" or "/car/ferrari" its not working.
But when i rename it from "/car/bmw" just to "/bmw" it works.
But i dont want to change the url name.
The url should stay how it is.

How can i dot it?

Comment: Where is your cookie checking logic?

Comment: I have put the cookie logic into the text. Please check up.